# Bind nginx to vpn address only

Tags: nginx, vpn, ip, ip-address

I am probably unnecessarily paranoid. But still also I think paranoid isn't too bad when it comes to security.

I have a web server running on a VPS. I run zerotier on all my VPS and my home machines. I then use Letsencrypt to run a https webserver.

Therefore, I have a DNS entry pointing to my webserver with the zerotier VPS address:
`myzerotier_webserver.mydomain.com   172.29.70.241`.

Now, I'd like to restrict access to my webserver to only participants in the zerotier network.

I tried this:

```
        listen 127.0.0.1:443 ssl http2;
        listen 172.29.0.0:443 ssl http2;
```

But this doesn't seem to work accessing this server from my connected home laptop entering `myzerotier_webserver.mydomain.com` in the browser.

I also tried by replacing `172.29.0.0` with the actual IP address of the VPS, e.g. `172.29.70.241`.

But it also didn't work.

Is this actually doable in some way? Should I do it differently maybe? Maybe it should work so the issue is some other configuration I got wrong?

Comment: Which webserver you are using? Nginx will get it's listeners from the line `listen <ip>:<port>`. If this doesn't work as expected, a line from the access log would be helpful.

Comment: I now know why this wasn't working: I was running nginx in a docker container, and the client IP was appearing as yet another network via `docker compose`: 192.168.80.1. Which means even the accepted solution actually doesn't work. In order to make it work, I had to extract nginx to run on the host, not in a container. Now I can filter by VPN address AND I can use multiple `server` instances of nginx listening to the same ports without interfering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `UFW`, you can just simply allow port access only for specific ranges. Here is an example:

`ufw allow from 172.29.70.0/24 to any port 443 proto tcp comment "HTTPS only zerotier"`

Change `172.29.70.0/24` to appropriate range.

Also don't forget to make default traffic rules:

`ufw default allow outgoing`

`ufw default deny incoming`

And enable UFW:

`ufw enable && ufw reload`

Comment: if you are accessing your server through ssh, don't forget to allow it's port: `ufw allow from any to any port 22 proto tcp comment SSH`. Execute this command BEFORE enabling UFW

Answer (score 1):

There is also an option to make it through NGINX configs, here it is:

```
location / {
  allow 45.43.23.0/24; # Change this to appropriate range
  deny all;
}
```

Comment: I like both suggestions, but prefer the ufw approach as I am personally likely to keep an eye on those rather more often. Thank you!